# How to access virtual attribute from a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using Rails 3.2.11 and Ruby 1.9.3 in Mac OS X Mountain Lion

I have a user model, and i created a virtual attribute called message

```
attr_accessor :message
```

In my code, i try this:

```
if condition == true
  self.message = "Value is True."
else
  self.message = "Value is not True"
```

In my controller, I try this

```
def method
  user = User.find(1)
  flash[:message] = user.message
end
```

But the flash message doesn't display anything. It's nil. How can I pass the value I set in the model to the controller? thanks a lot!

Comment: use instance variables instead of local variables. instance variables are prefixed with a `@` sign, so in your case it would be `@user` instead of `user`

Comment: It won't make a difference. In my actual code i used instance variables.

Comment: and even if "user" is only a local variable it's still a User object so it should still have the message attribute.

Comment: sorry, misread the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems logic: when you retrieve an object from your db, there is no reason it's attr_accessor should contain anything.

Sticking with your logic, you'd rather:

- remove the attr_accessor
- create a method in your User class.

like so:

```
def message 
  if condition
    "Value is True."
  else
    "Value is not True"
  end
end
```

Be aware you're coupling data and view which is not a good practice.